# Save as Site Template Error: Error exporting the site field named "HashTags"

Tags: site-template

I am having an urgent issue

> Error exporting the site field named "HashTags"

when saving a site as a template. All fields are created in GUI, no code. I don't have a `HashTag` field in my site, that I know of. Any idea why this is happening?

It happens regardless of if site content is included or not. Also verified with SharePoint 2013 Manager that no `Hashtag` field exists - anywhere.

I have checked the ULS log and at first it appears to be related to Oslo template. Something that I haven't customized, and this is a subsite anyway.

I also noticed that there was another error regarding an entry with the same key that seemed suppressed here. Not sure if it's related, but same correllation id:

> System.ArgumentException: An entry with the same key already exists.
>   at System.Collections.Generic.SortedList`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.ExportFields(SPFieldCollection
>   fields, String partitionName)
>
> MDSLog: An error page was detected by MDS: Context Page MP
>   (currentMPToken) =
>   ['|CUSTOMERTEMPLATE:|_LAYOUTS|15|ERRORV15.MASTER:0.15.0.0.0.15.0.4420.1017.4.FALSE.:en-US:en-US:RW'],
>   MP supplied by page in URL (originalMPToken) =
>   ['|CUSTOMERTEMPLATE:|_CATALOGS|MASTERPAGE|OSLO.MASTER:3.15.0.0.0.15.0.4420.1017.4.FALSE.:en-US:en-US:RW'],
>   Current Request URL =
>   ['https://www.xxxxxxx.com/CustomerTemplate/_layouts/15/error.aspx?ErrorText=Error
>   exporting the site field named
>   "HashTags".&ErrorCorrelationId=d3665e9c-c301-007d-53ed-066f93ff2cc7&AjaxDelta=1']

Answer (score 1):

looks like you have two fields within a list that are identical! keys i presume need to be unique!

> An entry with the same key already exists

that refers to a duplicate entry: where?

> ExportFields(SPFieldCollection fields, String partitionName)

within a field within a list!

whats the name of the field?

> HashTags

unfortunatly it doesnt state which list appart from the exception type and field name! so what list i have no idea but atleast you now know that its because of a list on that site with an identical key and the culprit field is called HashTags

have you customised any list? by that i mean have you put a customisation on a list to become sorted?

**EDIT**

just created this code!

it might be slow in running but it works! create a console app, copy past code in and just change the SPSite url for it to look at the given site:

```
        using (SPSite mysite = new SPSite("http://YourSiteUrl"))
        {

            using (SPWeb web = mysite.OpenWeb())
            {

                SPListCollection collList = web.Lists;

                foreach (SPList list in collList)
                {
                    foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
                    {
                        foreach (SPField field in item.Fields)
                        {
                            if (field.TypeAsString == "HashTags")
                            {
                                var listlocal = list.DefaultDisplayFormUrl;
                                var listName = list.Title;
                                var fld = field.Title;

                                    Console.Out.Write("List Url =" + listlocal);
                                    Console.Out.Write("List name =" + listName);
                                    Console.Out.Write("Field name =" + fld);
                                    Console.Out.WriteLine();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

to understand what it refers to when it states keys: [SortedList < TKey, TValue >.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132330(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can only have one type of key (no duplicates) but you can have multiple duplicate values! : [SortedList < TKey, TValue >.Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132379(v=vs.110).aspx)

**EDIT**

forgot to add console.read!

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using (SPSite mysite = new SPSite("http://yourTestSite"))
        {

            using (SPWeb web = mysite.OpenWeb())
            {

                SPListCollection collList = web.Lists;

                foreach (SPList list in collList)
                {
                    foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
                    {
                        foreach (SPField field in item.Fields)
                        {
                            if (field.TypeAsString != "HashTags")
                            {
                                var listlocal = list.DefaultDisplayFormUrl;
                                var listName = list.Title;
                                var fld = field.Title;

                                    Console.Out.Write("List Url =" + listlocal);
                                    Console.Out.Write("List name =" + listName);
                                    Console.Out.Write("Field name =" + fld);
                                    Console.Out.WriteLine();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        Console.Read();
    }
```

**EDIT**

somthing is wrong with your sever to bring that error :s , but did find a solution to your origonal question tho!

the solution is from [here](http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/154/t/184781.aspx).

Solution:

download [sharepoint manager 2013](http://spm.codeplex.com/).

goto parent site then look for Fields and deleted the HashTags field.

Comment: just ammended the answer! as we cant use the application due to major error I found a solution that should solve your issue!

Comment: You're so kind - I hate to tell you that I already did that (mentioned in my initial post). No hashtags found ... unless I'm missing something! I'm wondering if it's looking for the field and not finding it. I can't tell you enough how much I appreciate your help, though.

Comment: The only thing I'm doing 'unique' is that I have custom list forms. Otherwise, everything is standard ootb stuff (Content type, reusable workflows, etc.). I've been gradually adding pieces back in to a fresh subsite and trying to do the site template along the way.

Comment: lol that was the next thing i was going to say, could you make a fresh webapplication and a fresh subsite with nothing added in and make a template to see if it works! if it does then start to add things back in first oob then make a template and then lastly your custom list forms to see if its the culprit!

Comment: Probably not the whole web app - gotta get it done by tonight! Hoping that a fresh site will help ... more like praying. Nice to have someone to bounce ideas off of. Really appreciate it.

Comment: thats no problem ;) happy to help! i hope you do manage to get it sorted out, i know the feeling when things just dont work when they should... it drives you mad!

Comment: Thanks - and it's ALWAYS at the end right after you tell your project manager you're on time!

Comment: Ali - thank you again for your help and patience. I rebuilt the site in the GUI and the error disappeared!

Answer (score -1):

This ist the trouble and solution

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4341276/cannot-create-a-new-site-based-on-a-site-template-in-sharepoint-online